# Error when creating tables in MySQL with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, parse-error

I am having trouble creating my table in MySQL the table returns a ER_Parse_Error. I have been going through the table and cannot find what is causing the error, if anyone could have a look I would really appreciate it.
Below is the table:
[Table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zFTE.jpg)

And here is the error that it returns:
[Error returned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyMcS.png)

Edit: Here is the table in text:

```
//Cian
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "",
 database: "******"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log("Connected!");
var sql = "CREATE TABLE Order ( order_id INTEGER(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, order_description VARCHAR(255),order_date DATETIME,order_state VARCHAR(255),order_report_id integer(10))";
 con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log("Table created");
 });
});
```

And here is this error in text:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order ( order_id INTEGER(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, order_description VARCH' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:200:25)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (H:\Cloud\create_tables.js:120:6)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Handshake._callback (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:468:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (H:\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
```

Comment: Please add code and error messages as text to your question, instead of as images.

Comment: It looks that you have not closed the parentheses. After Order you have " ( ", but it is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL is case insensitive for the mysql reserved keywords and hence **Order** is treated same as **order** and **order** is MySQL reserved keyword and hence you can not create a table like that by the name of order.

So if you want to create your table by this name then use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.Order (order_id INTEGER(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  order_description VARCHAR(255), order_date DATETIME, order_state VARCHAR(255), order_report_id integer(10));
```

Here test is a test database where i want to create my table.